# Bittorrent extension for peers to send metadata files clarifing

Tags: metadata, bittorrent

Unfortunately I could not find in the specification (BEP 9).

Is it possible to download the torrent metadata from several peers?

Or it is restricted only one peer.

For example, the first chunk of the torrent file I download from one peer but the second chunk from the other peer?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BEP 9 is [here](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0009.html).

Yes, it is possible to download the metadata from several peers, assuming the .torrent file is greater than 16 kiB (the info-dictionary specifically). The info-dictionary is split up into 16 kiB blocks, and requested by specifying the index of the block you want. By requesting different blocks from different peers, you download it from multiple peers in parallel.